# Ansible don't run gradlew task

Tags: gradle, groovy, ansible

I have one groovy grails project.

I'm beginning with the ansible, and i'm trying run gradle build  with him.
but when I try it that way, it says there is no such task

> ansible-playbook build.yml -u root -v

and inside the server i can run

> ./gradlew war

this is my task.

```
- name: Build 
  shell : /tmp/git/test/gradlew war
```

When i run with task below, Ansible don't show the build and application tasks unlike when I run "./gradle tasks" inside the server

```
- name: Build 
  shell : /tmp/git/test/gradlew tasks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `chdir` argument of `shell` module:

```
- name: Build 
  shell : ./gradlew war
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/git/test
```

As per `gradle` documentation:

> The Wrapper shell script and batch file reside in the root directory
> of a single or multi-project Gradle build. You will need **to reference
> the correct path** to those files in case you want to execute the build
> **from a subproject directory** e.g. ../../gradlew tasks.

Note: More info here: [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).